# passing props for components to useMemo getting undefine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing data in the MemoDownloadsSubTab component but when I am trying to use it in MemoDownloadsSubTab in useMemo I am getting error data that is not defined I am not sure why this is happening let me know what I need to change so any another way I need to pass data in parent to child and us in the child component.

```
export const CorporateDetailsTable = ({
    userHistorySummary,
  }) => {
  
    const MemoDownloadsSubTab = React.useMemo(
      ({ data = [] }) => {
        return (
          <>
            {data?.length !== 0 &&
              data?.map((row, rowIndex) => {
                return (
                  <Box bgcolor="mainDetailsCard.primary" m={1} p={1} borderRadius={5}>
                    <Grid xs={12} item container spacing={2}>
                      <Grid item xs={12} sm={3}>
                        <Typography component="div">
                          <Box fontWeight="fontWeightBold" component="span" mr={1}>
                            SRN :
                          </Box>
                          {row.SRN}
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={12} sm={3}>
                        <Typography component="div">
                          <Box fontWeight="fontWeightBold" component="span" mr={1}>
                            Charge ID :
                          </Box>
                          {row.CHARGE_ID ? row.CHARGE_ID : "N/A"}
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </Box>
                );
              })}
          </>
        );
      }
      ,[userHistorySummary?.charges]);
    return (
      <>
        {userHistorySummary?.masterData?.length !== 0 ? (
          <Box mt={1}>
                return (
                          <MemoDownloadsSubTab
                            data={userHistorySummary?.charges}
                            title={"Charges Registered"}
                            cells={chargesCells}
                            classes={classes}
                          />
          </Box>
        ) : (
          <Typography variant="subtitle1" color="textSecondary">
            No Data Available
          </Typography>
        )}
      </>
    );
  };
```

Comment: try calling it as a function `MemoDownloadsSubTab({ data: ... })`

Comment: ({ data = [] }) => {
        here i need to call what you are suggesting

Comment: Right now the only prop it is receiving is `data`, while your implementation also shows `title`, `cell` and `className` being passed in. All of that aside, you really don't need to memoize this. Create your DownloadsSubTab component in a separate file, import it into your CorporateDetailsTable, and use it where needed.

Comment: yeah I'm using  data no need now for the other parts that I am passing

Comment: no actually what is happening data is coming too large so in UI in this component when I am showing it's re-rendering data to UI taking take to the response that's why I am using useMemo @Steve-Cutter-Blades

Comment: taking time to show

Comment: OK, I'll take your word for it. But you wouldn't need the dependency list in this memoization, as the prop is passed in to the internal function. I don't think the issue is needing to memoize your component. I think you probably need to memoize `userHistorySummary`. And, if your list of charges is extremely long, you may want to 'page' your list in some way.